# Netbeans 12.1 deploys WAR package in Project folder instead Tomcat webapps folder

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, deployment, war

I have a web project that I'm developing in NetBeans 12.1 and I'm using Tomcat 9.0.38 as the webserver.

When I click the Build button or the Run Button, Netbeans compiles and builds the WAR package but instead of deploying it in the Tomcat's webapps folder in `{CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/` it deploys the WAR file and extracts it in the NetBeans project folder `MyProject/target/`

After all this, Netbeans creates a config file in tomcat's config folder `{CATALINA_HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost/` called MyProject.xml that contains the path to the extracted war package in the project folder and the webapp works fine, but I don't want this deployment way.

Why is this happening?

I want to deploy directly from NetBeans to the Tomcat webapps folder. Do I have the wrong configuration?

Comment: No, you do not have anything obviously wrong with your configuration. What you are describing is standard NetBeans behavior: "in-place deployment".  I would be speculating if I tried to describe _why_ this is the default process - but I expect it has advantages over deploying directly to /webapps, while you are developing, debugging and using NetBeans to start/stop Tomcat. It certainly keeps more of a separation between development activities and deployment activities. Formal deployments are usually managed outside of the IDE by CI build processes, and/or source-code management systems.

Comment: thank U for the info. I asume that I have to work in this way in all the developing process and make a manual deployment for the final deploy right?

Comment: It probably depends on why you want your WAR to be in the /webapps folder. You can probably customize the build process you are using in NetBeans to ensure the war is added directly to the /webapps folder - although I am not sure how you would do that. Otherwise, yes - a deployment script can be used (which may be as simple as a file copy of the WAR to wherever you want it - e.g. into another Tomcat instance for testing).